# Suppress Model Error in Sailsjs when testing

Tags: sails.js

Using SailsJS 0.12.3 in my tests, I'm purposefully having my model validation fail, but it spits out those validation errors to the console making for a really messy test screen.

I know it's silly, but is there an easy way to suppress those errors?

```
debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: -------------------------------------------------------
  AuthController
    /csrfToken
      ✓ should return a _csrf token for me to use
    /api/v1/login
debug:  Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid
    at WLValidationError.WLError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the log level to `error` when you lift Sails:

```
sails.lift({log: {level: 'error'}});
```

Then you won't get debug-level messages anymore.